# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have a function as

```
private List<AccountViewModel> GetWorkableAccountsForTheMonth()
        {
            var result = GetAllAcountsForLoggedInAgents()
            .Where
                (
                    a =>
                        ("Deceased,DND,WN,WI,NC,NORESPONSE,SKIP,SHIFTED,SFU".Split(',').Any(x => x == a.DispCode.GetProperDispCode()))                            
                ).ToList();

        return result;

        }
```

The **GetAllAcountsForLoggedInAgents() is of type IQueryable.** and the **GetProperDispCode** is as under

```
public static string GetProperDispCode(this string dispCode)
        {
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dispCode) ? string.Empty : dispCode;
        }
```

While trying to execute this I am encountering the below error

*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

If I change the type to IEnumerable ( **GetAllAcountsForLoggedInAgents().ToList(**) ), it works... But i don't want to convert to IEnumerable from IQuerable at this point

What change i have to make ?

**Edit**

So, now I have made the changes as

```
string[] dispCodeArrays = "Deceased,DND,WN,WI,NC,NORESPONSE,SKIP,SHIFTED,SFU".Split(',');
            var result = GetAllAcountsForLoggedInAgents()
            .Where
                (
                    a =>
                        (dispCodeArrays.Any(x => x == a.DispCode.GetProperDispCode()))                       
                ).ToList();
```

Now the error is

**Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetProperDispCode(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

How to overcome this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method cannot be translated into a store expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846716/method-cannot-be-translated-into-a-store-expression)

Comment: You could try to overcome the missing part of invocation expressions in linq to entities, using LinqKit and AsExpandable extension method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667858/asexpandable-in-linq-to-entity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write LINQ to Entities code, you can only use .NET code that EF can convert to SQL, which it can't in your case.  Instead of using `String.Split` to split a literal `String` into an array, just create an array.

Comment: as per your advice, i have made the changes by splittign teh array outside.But while comparing with a.DispCode.GetProperDispCode(), it is throwing error. How can i handle that? Please look the edit

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar The answer to the new question is the first sentence in the answer. `When you write LINQ to Entities code, you can only use .NET code that EF can convert to SQL, which it can't in your case`. You cannot write `a.DispCode.GetProperDispCode()` because EF doesn't know how to turn the implementation of `GetProperDispCode` into SQL.

Answer (score 1):

`IQueryable` holds the query which will be executed on a DataSource, for example on db entities. It supports the operations which can be converted to a query while everything is executed finally as a single query.

The exception which you are getting is because it is unable to convert your code in a way it suits to the final query. You are trying to do a data-manupulation where the data is not yet exists.

At the end you mentioned that it is working when you say `ToList` to the method. Because when you say `ToList`, `FirstOrDefault` and operations similar to this, then the data is actually fetched from the DataSource to the memory. So the operation which you are trying to do will have the data to perform.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a `LINQ to Entity` query, you can only write Code which can be converted by entity framework to `SQL`. Because A `Linq to Entity` the query expression is
defined and stored in a query variable when the query is created, the execution of the query does not typically take place until iteration over the query variable begins. And for immediate execution you have to use `.ToList()` and the you can use `Non Sql Convertible` code.

So for your first Issue either yo have to create array of `String` outside the linq expression . or fetch the data into memory by using `.ToList()`.

And as you updated the question `a.DispCode.GetProperDispCode()` can not be converted into SQL query directly. So you have to use `ToList()` to get the data in memory and then use the method.

Or use a property which will hold the data of `a.DispCode.GetProperDispCode()` for you to use.